# Get Rid of Green Background in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I pasted a recipe from the internet to OneNote and now it has a green background color. Clicking No Color under Page Color does not work. Removing all formatting doesn't work. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Change the page size to Letter, (2) Close **all** notebooks and re-open this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to fix!

It is highlighted green due to being marked as read or unread, but if you press "CTRL-Q" it will remove it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the page colour doesn't change it, I see green when the updates are new.
It sounds like it hasn't synced / has just synced. I'd guess re-syncing may 'solve' it:

`Right-click the notebook
Sync now.`